# Is there an area of Feywild in the Underdark?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, campaign-settings, forgotten-realms

I'm considering running a campaign where I want the players to transition from the Feywild to the Underdark.

I've read through the Faerûn campaign setting and I can't see anything. The reason I want to make this transition is as a convenient way out of Returned Abeir, and also so they can fight their way up through the Underdark. It makes sense to me that if they enter the Feywild, then left ending up in the Underdark, there would need to be some cross over point in the Underdark. Does such a place exist? Or do I have free reign to make one up?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**There is a specific Feywild for the Underdark, and it's called the Feydark**

It is found in the [Underdark Supplement for 4e](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/078695387X).

Here is an [excerpt about the Feydark](http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ex/20100108).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - How did I not know the archive site was a thing? Awesome.

Comment: This is why link only answers are bad, guys (link rot)